# Sci-fi horror where people were taken over by aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens

This should be an easy one but I'll be damned if I can find it!

It is a sci-fi horror flick like "Invasion of the Body Snatchers" but somewhat different. As I recall, the viewer never saw the actual process where humans were taken over by the alien presence. The human replacement had no emotion and when confronted with an actual human, it would let out a high-pitched squeal as a warning to the other aliens.

The movie follows two people who seem to be the last of the humans. They adopt an emotionless persona to hide among the now-alien population. They meet at the end of the movie, I believe in a park, where the woman smiles at the man thinking that he still is in hiding when the man lets out the high-pitched squeal of the alien! The movie ends there.

What is this movie?

Comment: see also the original 1956 version (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212607/looking-for-sci-fi-movie-with-feeling-less-duplicates)

Answer (score 9):

That **was** *Invasion of the Body Snatchers* [(the 1978 version)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_the_Body_Snatchers_(1978_film)).

Here's that famous last scene:

Comment: There are [multiple versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Body_Snatchers#Film_adaptations) of Invasion of the Body Snatchers, so I guess Ernesto probably saw another.

Comment: Given Donald Sutherland, this must be the 1978 version.

Comment: @ThomasWeinbrenner As far as I recall the 1978 one was the only one where humans don't win eventually. So that must be the one Ernesto means.

Comment: It is the one he asked for, but when he said "like "Invasion of the Body Snatchers" but somewhat different" he compared it probably to another version he once watched.

Comment: Isn't there one version called *Pod People*? Ah.. yes... *Invasion of the Pod People* was a mock buster coinciding with *Invasion of the Body Snatchers*. :)

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel Roseman has answered, you're talking about the 1978 version of "Invasion of the Body Snatchers".

You are presumably thinking of the (original) [1956 version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFnSxeDfENk)[image]