# Sci-fi movie with feeling-less duplicates

Tags: story-identification, movie

- **Plot Details**

  - People address doctor about spouses becoming completely feeling-less.
  - Doctor discovers that alien race is taking over Earth.
- **Release**

  - Probably 1940s. Pretty old movie.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From that brief description, it sounds like the original [Invasion of the Body Snatchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_the_Body_Snatchers)

Comment: This has to be it.  The main character is a doctor, and the initial slow reveal of the alien threat is based largely on reports from spouses and children that the "snatched" aren't acting like themselves.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe a long guess, but could it be [Invasion of the Body Snatchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_the_Body_Snatchers) from 1956?

Comment: Are there large pods in your memory? In Invasion of the Body Snatchers big pods are laid next to people and a replica comes out of the pod that looks like the person they've taken over. A big part of the story.